# Why is my JS code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying is just to print a message in console by invoking function immediately. Here is the example:

```
function (a){
    return function (a){
        console.log('msg' + a);
    }
}(3);
```

*PS*

Please don't judge me too fast I'm only started studying JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a self invoking anonnymous function you need to encapsulate it:

```
(function (a){
    return function (a){
        console.log('msg' + a);
    }
}(3));
```

Then as you have a closure the value won't pass to the returned function so try this and you will see:

```
(function (a){
    return function (a){
        console.log('msg' + a);
    }
}(3)(7));
```

This is an example of the (3)(7) written in simple words:

```
var f1 = function (a){
    console.log(a);
    return function (a){
        console.log('msg' + a);
    }
}

var inheritFunction = f1(3); // Calling f1(3) won't return what you are looking for.
inheritFunction(7); // Returns the original value
```

Comment: Very interesting example. But I don't understand the difference between them. I mean this diff between `}(3));` and `}(3)(7));`

Comment: Glad it helped. Are you learning from Codeschool?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's form Codeschool.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap it with parenthesis to make your code valid javascript syntax. I guess you wanted to declare some anonymous function. Here's how this is done:

```
(function() {
    return function(a) {
        console.log('msg' + a);
    }
})()(3);
```

or maybe you meant:

```
(function someFunc(a) {
    console.log('msg' + a);
})(3);
```

In the first case your anonymous scope returns a function, so you need to first invoke it before passing any parameters to it.

In the second case, it's just an anonymous function being declared and executed immediately by passing the parameters directly.

Comment: I'm going to stop fixing your post, now (and just up-vote you instead)... ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
(function(a) {
  return function(a) {
    console.log('msg' + a);
  }
})(3)(5);
```

It says `msg5`, and you figure out why ;)